# Playing a sine-wave signal using rsound

Tags: audio, lisp, racket

I wrote this code after reading the rsound documentation in Racket:

```
#lang racket
(provide (all-defined-out))
(require rsound)


(define (sunet)
  (sine-wave 880))

(signal-play sunet)

(stop)
```

I used the "sine-wave" function on a 880 Hz frequency and stored it into the function "sunet". Then I applied on it the function "signal-play" that plays signals as sound. I got this error:

```
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: #<network/s>
  arguments.:
   880
>
```

Isn't "sine-wave" a function and isn't it taking frequency as an argument?

Comment: Maybe it would be clearer if you mention in the title that this is a problem with `rsound` specifically?

Comment: this is a great question, and I'm glad you found the answer (I think there's sample code in the docs somewhere). I also know that this can confuse many people; if you have an idea for a better error message, I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 3):

I read more of the documentation of *rsound* and read about *networks*. Apparently you need to create a network with the input signal and the output signal that gets out to something like *signal-play*.

This would be the code that I needed yesterday:

```
(define sunet
  (network ()
       [A5 <= sine-wave 880]
       [out = A5]))

(signal-play sunet)

(sleep 3)

(stop)
```

And with two signals to create a powerchord:

```
(define sunet
  (network ()
       [E2 <= sine-wave 82]
       [B2 <= sine-wave 123]
       [out = (+ E2 B2)]))
(signal-play sunet)
(sleep 3)
(stop)
```

So, I just answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

This was harder than I expected. Turns out `sine-wave` is not a function but a network. The following will play a sine wave.

```
    #lang racket
    (require rsound)

    (define s (network ()
                 [a <= sine-wave 880]
                 [out = a]))
    (signal-play s)
```

I do not know why the following simpler program does not work:

```
    #lang racket
    (require rsound)

    (define s (network ()
                 [out = sine-wave 880]))
    (signal-play s)
```

Comment: @john-clements ? Any idea?

Comment: This works though: `#lang racket
(require rsound)
(define s (network ()
                   [out <= sine-wave 880]))
(signal-play s)
`